# How can I mount SFTP/SSH in Finder on OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: finder, ssh, mount

My Question is seemingly simple. I need to mount an SSH/SFTP volume and make it visible in finder to be able to use it as if it were a local volume (think SMB share). I have tried everything I could find (MacFUSE + sshfs (whatever version), Macfusion (couldn't install),...).

Is there anyway to do this seemingly simple thing? It feels like I'm missing something here. Also, I'm not looking for an SFTP client for download/upload. My personal machine is an Ubuntu box, and that's easily doable on that.

Answer (score 116):

The best solution I've found today (2017) is to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and [Cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask) to install [osxfuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/) and [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs). Note that Homebrew core [deprecated all FUSE-related formulae](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/64491) in 2020 so you need to install `sshfs` from a tap:

```
brew install --cask macfuse
brew install gromgit/fuse/sshfs-mac
```

And then:

```
sshfs username@hostname:/remote/directory/path /local/mount/point -ovolname=NAME
```

It works! :-)

Comment: I don't see files mounted this way in finder for some reason

Comment: I guess you would have to mount the disk under /Volumes, no?

Comment: Be careful when using this tool to mount in Volumes.  I messed up and specified /Volumes (itself) as the mount point and it killed the folder.  I know...dumb, but...it happened.  That made Finder unhappy.  Disk repair fixed it but it was a scary 20 minutes.

Comment: I get: No available Casks for sshfs

Comment: @JensTimmerman, sshfs moved from a brew cask to a brew tap, updated the answer, see above

Comment: If you are using ssh keys remember that path to key must be absolute path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393502/how-do-i-specify-the-key-file-for-sshfs

Comment: This is perfect. It worked for me straight away using the commands as described and the performance is just so much better than using a samba mount.

Comment: @ccpizza What is `$1`?

Comment: It would ask me for the password and then print `remote host has disconnected`.

Comment: You should do something with that Cask link...

Comment: I used MacPorts to install it, but same basic principle applies: `sudo port install  sshfs` - it will automatically bring in `osxfuse` and any needed dependencies.

Answer (score 29):

Well, [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/) *was* going to be my answer but since you've tried that I'll recommend my second favourite app when it comes to mounting shares: [Panic's Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit/). It's new, very awesome, feature lets you mount any share that it can connect to in the UI as a "disk" in your Finder that you can drag files to. SFTP, SSH, S3...very cool.

Comment: My #1 issue with MacFusion is that it doesn't support key-based authentication, so I can't use it with the server I usually use.  Transmit handles that nicely (but isn't free).

Comment: Transmit Disk has been removed as of Transmit 5.6.0 https://library.panic.com/transmit/transmit-disk/

Comment: According to https://help.panic.com/transmit/transmit5/transmit-disk/, there is slight hope it might come back at some point later

Answer (score 10):

I use [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) for this task. It's a cross-platform (but native on mac) app that is full of features and it's free to use. You can support the developers by donating or buying it directly from the Mac App Store.

The developer also has an application named [Mountainduck](https://mountainduck.io/) which let you mount the path you want to a folder and access it through Finder app.

Answer (score 6):

As of March 2013, the current free software solution is [macFUSE](https://osxfuse.github.io/) plus a package for SSHFS (a download link on Fuse for OS X webpage).

[Macfusion](http://macfusionapp.org/) is a GUI for easy mounting/unmounting remote shares but it needs to be [patched](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS) to work with SSHFS/Fuse for OS X.

Comment: Correct link is https://osxfuse.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

Best ones that you can use are Transmit, like has been said before, or Expandrive, which is probably more like what you're looking for, as finder integration is its main feature.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install VSCode
2. Extensions - Install Remote - SSH (from Microsoft)
3. Bottom left >< icon. Open remote window
4. Map your remote drive e.g./home/joe
5. Browse the directories in Explorer view
6. Drag and drop to upload, right click and download as needed

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/index.html) (35$+). I successfully used the Windows version of the same product, so I expect the same from the OS X version. Too bad, that they require you to buy separate licenses for Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have `FUSE for OS X` installed (e.g. you got it directly from SourceForge), then @eskatos solution can reduced to just installing `sshfs` instead of the whole cask which includes FUSE.  You can do this by using:

```
brew install homebrew/fuse/sshfs
```

You might want to check if you have the latest version of `FUSE for OS X` through your `System Preferences` while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

Given I cannot comment, I'll add to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193043/176108) that if you want to unmount the recently mounted **sshfs** disk, you need to execute:

```bsh
umount <MOUNTPOINT>
```

The sshfs man page states that you should do `fusermount -u <MOUNTPOINT>` but [that command doesn't exist in macOS](https://github.com/osxfuse/sshfs/issues/31#issuecomment-263013776)

Comment: Try `diskutil unmount  MountPoint|DiskIdentifier|DeviceNode`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are having problems unmounting the disk, you can unmount it simply writing

```
umount ~/mounted/folder
```

hope it saves some headache to someone else

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you edit this to elaborate how it addresses the question on how to mount? Be sure you complete the [tour] as well, it helps get the best reception when you participate.

Answer (score -1):

[ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/apps/expandrive/) is a commercial version with an outrageous $50 price tag, but is very clean and slick.

It also mounts Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, Amazon S3, OwnCloud folders, plus a bunch more and supports ssh keys and sftp.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend ExpanDrive any more - my copy simply won't connect to anything at all (either basic SSH or Dropbox/Google etc. - repeated oauth errors for the latter) and didn't get anywhere with support.

Answer (score -1):

You can download [CloudMounter](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloudmounter-cloud-encryption/id1130254674?mt=12) from the Mac App Store.

This app, permit virtual mount units like, GoogleDrive, DropBox, S3, SFTP, FTP, etc.

Comment: Does it work on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score -5):

I use Filezilla, its free, connect as sftp.