# How do I connect to my web server on mac?

Tags: macbook-pro

On Ubuntu, I was able to connect to another server using "places". Is there anything like that in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Finder, choose Go > Connect To Server (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and type in the URL or IP for the server (including the protocol if not afp).

Comment: I usually connect using putty on Windows. Is this the same? Because its rejecting my login.

Comment: What protocol is it using? It should accept it as long as it supports the connection.

Comment: I dont know if "connection type" is the same as protocol, but it says SSH.

Comment: Finder does not directly support SSH connections. See [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5209/4024) for methods of enabling ssh through Finder, consider purchasing a separate application to connect to the server, or just use the command line.

Comment: i think i'll learn to use command line

Answer (score 1):

The application I would call the most "PuTTY-like" in MacOSX is JellyFiSSH. OSX has a native terminal application, and you can go on ahead and use it for all command line work, but JellyFiSSH has a lot of nice helpers like saving "bookmarks" for connections, bookmark grouping, tunnel management, and more.

It does NOT, support auto-discovery. I don't know what Ubuntu's "Place" looks like, so I cannot distinctly comment. However, you emntion SSH, and you mention PuTTY, so I'm going to recommend JellyFiSSH. It's a great helper application to an otherwise daunting command line task.

[JellyFiSSH](http://www.grepsoft.net/jellyfissh.html) (Homepage). [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jellyfissh/id416399476?mt=12) ($3)