# Is there anyway to mount a webpage?

Tags: macbook-pro

My professor requires me to go to the website and login and check the individual folders for updates. It is using http and I am wondering if there is a way to mount it as a drive similar to SSH and macfusion.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5209/how-to-mount-sftp-ssh-in-finder-on-osx-snow-leopard

Comment: That is clearly asking about ssh and sftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mount a http/https server as a filesystem since it won't provide a directory table for you. (I left a comment on why httpfs isn't what you need)

The best way to do the task is to make a list of the URLs you need to check and use a shell script (run from Automator for convenience perhaps?)

You will need to USE curl or wget which will do the http downloading for you (they both provide post and http basic auth support for sending login info, however you probably need to install them on Mac Os X, off the top of my head I've forgotten.)

You can get fancy and use diff to check automatically for changes in the files, so that you only need to get personally involved with the process when you really have to.

Need more info, I'll happily expand on this.

#### References:

- [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) and [Curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)
- [Diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)

Answer (score 0):

http://httpfs.sourceforge.net/

The webpage doesn't appear to have been updated since September 2006, but the downloads area has a release from a year ago.  Source code only, but reported to work on 10.4+.  You'll also need to install [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/).

Comment: I wish macfusion had httpfs.

Comment: I'm not sure how can I "mount" with this?

Comment: Ok, httpfs is not suitable for your task, it will not mount a http directory structure, it will only mount fs style images like ISOs, DMGs etc.  What you need really is a script to grab the URLs you want.