# How I can browse servers over SSH in visually?

Tags: snow-leopard, software-recommendation, ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mount SFTP/SSH in Finder on OSX Snow Leopard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5209/how-to-mount-sftp-ssh-in-finder-on-osx-snow-leopard)

I remotely manage many servers every day. I'm currently using Nautilus in Ubuntu and it's awesome.

Before buying a Mac, I'd like to know if there's anything similar or equivalent to browse SSH servers visually over SSH for OSX.

Comment: Can you give an example (maybe a picture) of what you mean by "browse SSH servers visually over SSH"? Do you mean the OS generates a list machines in a GUI that you can pick from to then ssh in to? Right now it's ambiguous what you're trying to mimic on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -X
```

will do it in mac, this will open X11 on your mac when you start an x application in your ssh session to your server.

the ssh client is native to mac (because it is BSD based) and can be started from the terminal

If you are managing windows servers RDP for mac is excellent as well.

Comment: I tried using `ssh -X` and it didn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @daviesgeek: you have to start a graphical application once you're logged. For example, if you log in to a Linux box with GNOME installed, you could type `gnome-open .` and it would open the GNOME file manager with the distant files on your local machine. That said, this solution will be generally slower than using `sshfs` or `sftp` since the graphics will go through your SSH connection.

Comment: I pinged you in chat. Can we continue there? I have more questions.

Answer (score 4):

You could connect to your remote host via sshfs over fuse. An implementation for OSX is [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/). A nice fronted for macfuse is [MacFusion](http://macfusionapp.org/).
A crossplatform solution for accessing ssh/sftp enabled hosts is [MuCommander](http://www.mucommander.com/) which provides a commander-like interface to your remote host.

Answer (score 4):

[Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) does sftp so it can display remote files through an SSH connection.