# Mount SFTP on M1 macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh, mount, ftp

After about 6 years of using Ubuntu I am switching for the first time to macOS given the remarkable specification of M1 chip.

One of the main use of my laptop (that ran on Ubuntu) was to connect to a Server also running on Ubuntu.

I guess macOS would surely allow SSH via terminal as this is a very basic command. What I am not sure if it allows mounting external devices like Ubuntu as shown in image below,

[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu Connect to Server feature showing recent sftp:// servers]

In Ubuntu we had Connect To Server feature, which used the SFTP protocol. This feature would mount the remote server onto my laptop allowing easy browsing and shifting of files.

Will this be possible on the new MacBook Air with M1 chip? Of course we could use SFTP via terminal, but I am looking for the GUI mounting feature of Ubuntu. What will be the closest alternative of 'Connect to Server' feature of Ubuntu for macOS?

I found a solution in this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsCDShafzmg). Here however it is demonstrated only for connecting to Windows and Mac systems. Can this be used to connect to Ubuntu Server also?

Note: I simply want to mount the filesystem of Ubuntu onto my macOS and security is not that important.

Comment: You mean from command line or from GUI? From the Finder, it's just Cmd/K. tbh, I'm not sure if it supports sftp, I've never tried it. smb is fine.

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5209/how-can-i-mount-sftp-ssh-in-finder-on-os-x-snow-leopard/193043

Comment: Might be easier to run a Samba server on Linux side, and connect to that from macOS (unless you need security features only available with sftp).

Comment: @nohillside I simply want to mount the filesystem of Ubuntu onto my MacOS. Security not that important.

Comment: ftp is a file *transfer* solution. If you want to mount a drive, use smb/Samba.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from macOS in the Finder you can mount remote file systems over a number of protocols.

In Finder hit `cmd-K` or Connect to Server from the Go menu, and you'll be presented with a dialog box.

Out of the box you're better off using Samba (SMB) sharing from Ubuntu, but you can install sshfs which uses FUSE to mount through SSH.